# (Meteor) Velocity Mocha fails - mocha.log Error: kill ENOSYS

Tags: node.js, meteor, mocha.js, meteor-velocity

I am not able to use velocity with mocha, i added it using 'meteor add mike:mocha' and started the app using 'meteor' it displays the following:

> I20151115-13:33:18.986(2)? [velocity] mocha is starting a mirror at
>   http://local host:29466/. I20151115-13:33:18.992(2)? [velocity] ***
>   Meteor Tools is installing *** I20151115-13:33:18.993(2)? This takes a
>   few minutes the first time. I20151115-13:33:18.997(2)? [velocity] You
>   can see the mirror logs at: tail -f D:
>   \Github\shopaholic.meteor\local\log\mocha.log

The mocha.log contains this:

> node.js:762
>           throw errnoException(process._errno, 'kill');
>                 ^ Error: kill ENOSYS
>       at errnoException (node.js:573:13)
>       at process.kill (node.js:762:15)
>       at process. (C:\tools\tool-env\cleanup.js:33:13)
>       at process.g (events.js:180:16)
>       at process.emit (events.js:92:17)
>       at Signal.wrap.onsignal (node.js:790:46)

All i get is this and it just stuck showing 'mocha - mirror starting'

[image]

I am using windows 7 64 bit and i have latest node installed i also installed mocha globally just in case i don't know if it matters also all meteor packages are up to date and meteor as well.

Comment: Is the Java JDK installed? (Not the JRE)

Comment: I guess not, would it help if i do install it?

Comment: Installed Java JDK but no hope :)

Comment: Meteor on Windows always carries an extra air of mystery :(

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @DanielBernhard Actually no, I just installed a linux vm and did all the work on it.

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Cool. A guy on my team was having this problem. Newest versions of velocity + jasmine seem to fix it, for what it's worth.

Comment: @DanielBernhard Thanks for sharing the information, surely it's nice to know that there is a fix for this issue :)